# grouping items from array of object into array in the same object with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

well my Question is : how can i group some items from an object in new array filed
for Exemple :

```
myArray = [
  { Name: "Alex", Age :"13" , Email: " Alex @gmail.com" },
  { Name: "Eva",  Age :"24",  Email: " Eva @gmail.com"  },
  { Name: "Adem", Age :"60",  Email: " Adem @gmail.com" },
  { Name: "Jack", Age :"20",  Email: " Jack @gmail.com" }
]
```

The result that i want is :

```
myArray = [
  { Name: "Alex", Details: [{ Age: "13", Email: " Alex @gmail.com" }] },
  { Name: "Eva",  Details :[{ Age: "24", Email :" Eva @gmail.com"  }] },
  { Name: "Adem", Details :[{ Age: "60", Email :" Adem @gmail.com" }] },
  { Name: "Jack", Details :[{ Age: "20", Email :" Jack @gmail.com" }]}
]
```

Comment: why your new array is named `myArray` and not `newArray` ? you want to update the original array ?

Comment: @MisterJojo If we want to talk about naming sense and convention there's a lot more to work on that myArray and newArray xd

Comment: @Scar I don't understand your answer, my translation makes no sense

Comment: @MisterJojo what i meant is that the snippet posted doesen't respect naming convention, and needs further refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that

```js
const 
  myArray = [
    { Name:"Alex", Age:"13" , Email:" Alex @gmail.com" },
    { Name:"Eva",  Age:"24",  Email:" Eva @gmail.com"  },
    { Name:"Adem", Age:"60",  Email:" Adem @gmail.com" },
    { Name:"Jack", Age:"20",  Email:" Jack @gmail.com" }
    ]
, newArray = myArray.map(({Name, ...others})=>({Name, Details:[{...others}]}))

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myArray = [
  {Name:"Alex", Age:"13" , Email:" Alex @gmail.com"},
  {Name:"Eva",  Age:"24",  Email:" Eva @gmail.com" },
  {Name:"Adem", Age:"60",  Email:" Adem @gmail.com"},
  {Name:"Jack", Age:"20",  Email:" Jack @gmail.com"}
]

const newArray = myArray.map(i => {
   return {Name: i.Name, Details: [{Age: i.Age, Email: i.Email}]}
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this you will get the exact result
myArray = [
  {Name: "Alex", Age :"13" , Email :" Alex @gmail.com"},
  {Name: "Eva", Age :"24", Email :" Eva @gmail.com"},
  {Name: "Adem", Age :"60", Email :" Adem @gmail.com"},
  {Name: "Jack", Age :"20", Email :" Jack @gmail.com"}
]

newArray = [];

for(let details of myArray) {
  let groupedInfo = {Details: []};
  let groupedDetails = {}
  for(let info in details) {
        if(info == 'Name') {
            groupedInfo[info] = details[info];
        }
      else {
        groupedDetails[info] = details[info];
      }
    }
    groupedInfo['Details'].push(groupedDetails);
    newArray.push(groupedInfo);
}

console.log(newArray);
```